# Using post with oData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an application that is using oData. So far I have been using only http get request. I would like to start using http post request as well. I got the following code in the Web API:
In the WebAoucConfig I have:

```
var queryPostAction = builder.Function("QueryPostAction");
queryPostAction.ReturnsCollection<Test>();
queryPostAction.Parameter<string>("Query");
```

In the custom function controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("QueryPostAction")]
public IHttpActionResult QueryPostAction(string Query)
{
    List<Test> listTest = new List<Test>();  
    return Ok(listTest);
}
```

And in the application I am calling it like:

```
var test = DataConnection.context.QueryPostAction("test");
```

I put a brake point in the custom function controller but I am not hitting it at all

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the method as below

var test = DataConnection.context.QueryPostAction(Query="test");

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work is, that `Function` can be only called via GET requests, and actions using a `POST` requests. `Functions` parameters needs to be in the URL query, and `Action` as a request body (JSON format, key value).

In case of `Action` requests, you can't just simply put an argument in your function. The way how you can access your parameters is by using `ODataActionParameters`.

Try as follow:

```cs
-var queryPostAction = builder.Function("QueryPostAction");
+var queryPostAction = builder.Action("QueryPostAction");
queryPostAction.ReturnsCollection<Test>();
queryPostAction.Parameter<string>("Query");
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("QueryPostAction")]
-public IHttpActionResult QueryPostAction(string Query)
+public IHttpActionResult QueryPostAction(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    List<Test> listTest = new List<Test>(); 
+   string query = parameters["Query"];
    return Ok(listTest);
}
```

More details and examples you can find here: [Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions)